# PSQL: Invalid input syntax for integer on COPY

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a .txt file with a plain list of words (one word on each line) that I want to copy into a table. The table was created in Rails with one row: t.string "word".

The same file loaded into another database/table worked fine, but in this case I get:

```
pg_fix_development=# COPY dictionaries FROM '/Users/user/Documents/en.txt' USING DELIMITERS ' ' WITH NULL as '\null';
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "aa"
CONTEXT:  COPY dictionaries, line 1, column id: "aa"
```

I did some googling on this but can't figure out how to fix it. I'm not well versed in SQL. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you created that table in Rails then you almost certainly have *two* columns, not one. Rails will add an `id serial` column behind your back unless you tell it not to; this also explains your "input syntax for integer" error: COPY is trying to use the `'aa'` string from your text file as a value for the `id` column.

You can tell [COPY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html) which column you're importing so that the default `id` values will be used:

```
copy dictionaries(word) from ....
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I deleted the created_at and updated_at columns and used your syntax.